# Download large file in LAN using C#

Tags: c#, networking, download, microsoft-bits, bits-service

I am making an application which installs software on request from user.
I am having zip files saved on server for software installation.
On request approval i download the file on the requested machine using Microsoft BITS service.
But there are several issues as my application run under Administrator privilege and BITS does not support 'run as'.
Is there other way to download large file over network???
Please help..